# Disable href in a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I am developing a js plugin that people can embed on their websites/wordpress. The js is loaded using ajax and modify some  tags in the DOM (using a specific class). The plugin modifies these  tags to embed a google map with custom pins coming from an API.

I would like to use an href to link the API url and the plugin. However, using this href implies that clicking on the map redirects to the api which is not what I want. I could use `e.preventDefault()` but it disables the inner google map links (the pins are links to a detailed page of the place, these links are loaded from the API).

So what I would like is to simply disable the plugin container href without disabling the children links. Here is a sample :

```
<a href="link-to-the-api" class="my-plugin-class disable-me">
    <div class="google-map">
        <a href="link-to-place1" class="dont-disable-me">place 1</a>
        <a href="link-to-place2" class="dont-disable-me">place 2</a>
        <a href="link-to-place3" class="dont-disable-me">place 3</a>
    </div>
</a>
<script src="http://my-custom-map.com"></script>
```

EDIT : I forgot to mention that I wanted to use  and href to improve the SEO of the API.

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried `return false;` instead? I think with that, the event should still bubble, although the link won't redirect...

Comment: I think this is invalid HTML. You cannot use `<a>` inside of `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by DanFromGermany, you cannot nest `<a>` elements.

Instead, why not use a `div`? Since you appear to be handling clicks on it via `onclick`, you can use `div` just fine. You can then check `e.target || e.srcElement` to see if the click was actually on one of the links. If it is, allow the event to pass through. Otherwise, handle it using the API.

You'd be best off using a `data-*` attribute, such as `data-api="link-to-the-api"`, and accessing that attribute.

Comment: Mmh. You're right. Actually I'm currently using data-* to add this link, but I wanted to improve the SEO of the API using `<a>` and `href`. I know that the twitter widget embed an `<a>` and then replace it by an `<iframe>`. I'll probably do the same with a div instead of the `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="return false;"` to prevent changing page.

Also you should know that using `<a>` tag inside `<a>` is not allowed.